# Increment a cookie value by 1

Tags: cookies, setcookie

I have a text field and a submit button. User submits an email id and on successful submission a lightbox will load. On successful submission I am setting a cookie and initially assigning a value of 1. Though I am able to set the increment I am not able to assign the incremented value to the cookie value.

```js
var demoCookieCount = getCookie("democount");
$('#online-demo-lightbox-button').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
demoCookiecount++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the new value into the cookie. Try something like that in the end:

`document.cookie = cookieName + cookieContent + cookieExpires;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the new value in the cookie by using setCookie() or something like

```
function setCookie(democount, ++demoCookiecount, 1)
{
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally somehow got through. This piece of code worked

```
//setting the Cookie democount with initial value of 1
setCookie("democount", '1');
//getting the value of 'democount' cookie and assigning it to a variable
var demoCookieCount = getCookie("democount");
$('#sample-button').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
//increment the variable on every click
demoCookieCount++;
//set the incremented value of demoCookieCount variable to democount cookie
setCookie("democount",demoCookieCount);
// assigning the value of demoCookiecount to variable 123
var123 = getCookie("democount");
});
```